# Dropdown menu in table with default values (React, Typescript, Material-UI)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I was wondering how to do have my table with a dropdown menu with default value selected based on fetched data.

[image: Table with preselect default values]

I want my table to look like that.
Here is my code for that specifc cells

```
    const { batchData, defaultVals } = useBatchData(updateObj);

    return (
    ...
    {batchData.map((item: IImportItem, index) => {
        return (<React.Fragment key={index}>
            <TableCell align='center'>
                <Select
                    defaultValue={defaultVals [index]}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                        <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={"val1"}>Val1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={"val2"}>Val2</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </TableCell>
    ...
```

So I get the data and use useState from react to update the defaultVals array but I can't figure out how to set it up so when it load and I have the data the dropdown refreshes.

If was set from the begining like this

`const defaultVals : string[] = ["val1","val1","val1","val2]`

I know it works and my array eventually looks like that but it needs a few seconds to get the data so my question is how can I refresh and/or rerender the dropdown menus with the default values once I get them.

I hope that is clears and thanks for the help.

Comment: Eventually you can consider to set `defaultVals` to [] and render `<TableCell />` only when `defaultVals` is not empty. In this way you will avoid annoying re-render or refresh.

Comment: Yes!! I didn't even think about conditonal rendering. Thanks that was exactly what I needed. Much appreciated

Comment: Actually I still need to refresh the whole page because if some other data updates then auto-selected options gets out of synch with the rest of the data